# Download artifacts No artifacts found

Tags: gitlab

Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:00
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: sitespeed-results/: no matching files
ERROR: No files to upload
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: browser-performance.json: no matching files
ERROR: No files to upload
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded

#### gitlab-ci.yaml example :

include:
template: Verify/Browser-Performance.gitlab-ci.yml

browser_performance:
variables:
URL: https://example.com
DEGRADATION_THRESHOLD: 5

Comment: Not quite sure what your after here. Could you provide additional context about what your doing and what you hope to happen instead of just the ci terminal output?

Answer (score 1):

This error usually happens when there are no matching files found. Either move the files to the main directory, or specify the correct path to the files and folders. No matter where your script ends, gilab runner always searches for these files in the main/root directory of the project.

Answer (score 1):

create a new folder inside `$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR` then copy your desired artifacts in that new folder?

After that, use the new folder as your artifacts.

See sample step below:

```
- step:
      name: XXXX
      image:
         name: YYYY
         username: $xxxy
         password: $yyyy
      script:
        - mvn clean install --file $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/xxxx/pom.xml
        - mkdir –p $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/dist
        - cp -R xxx/target/* $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/dist
        - ls -lah $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/dist
      artifacts:
          - dist/**
```

I hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Check the path you have provided in the artifacts section:

```
  artifacts:
      paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR
      expire_in: 1 week
```

If you are choosing files only with some specific extensions like below, then GitLab Runner will not be able to find files with any other extensions:

```
  artifacts:
      paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/*.xlsx
      expire_in: 1 week
```

So be careful with what are you mentioning in the "paths"